# Closing AddIn in ArcGIS with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio

I was working in ArcGIS 10.2 with VBA but now I work with Visual Studio 2013 to create addins.

I need to close all processes, I did this with the **end statement** in VBA but I don't find a command to do the same process in Visual Studio.

Comment: No need to shout... Can you show some code please, so we know where you're up to. Do you want to deactivate your tool or close a form or do you want to save/exit ArcMap entirely?

Comment: ' Step. Do your big process here.
  boolCont = True
  For i = 0 To 10000
    Application.StatusBar.Message(0) = Str(i)
    'Check if the cancel button was pressed. If so, stop process
    boolCont = pTrkCan.Continue
    If Not boolCont Then
      **End**
    End If
  Next i

  ' Done
  Set pTrkCan = Nothing
  Set pStepPro = Nothing
  Set pProDlg = Nothing

Comment: i need something that replace the **End** stament in visual studio

Comment: It's better if you post your code in your question (use the edit button) and format it with the {} button to make it easier to read. Calling End https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116090/how-do-i-kill-a-process-using-vb-net-or-c can be dangerous as the Esriaddin is tied (joined) with the ArcMap process so could conceivably terminate both processes or lead to undesired behavior. If I could understand more about why you feel the need to ungracefully exit and what you're doing at the time I could suggest alternatives.

Comment: i am showing a progressdialog (using the IProgressDialog2 interface) to display a process progress then i need to finish the process (only Esriaddin) when cancel button is clicked or an error occurs

Comment: According to the docs End is still a statement https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement which you should be able to use as before. If you're executing a process you would probably be looping and then checking the ITrackCancel on each iteration like example http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriFramework/esriFramework_IProgressDialog2_Example.htm if false then put in some cleanup code and exit with a Return statement (which will exit the sub) instead of an End or you could raise an exception and catch it.